# Ways to beautify leaflet map in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, react-leaflet, shiny-reactivity

I've ** finally** gotten the drop-down menu to work, but have a few lingering questions:

- my leaflet map automatically opens on the "all" option in the drop down menu, but doesn't display all the circle markers (however it does show the markers when you select artist name in the dropdown) -- how do I get it to show all the circle markers when the map opens (like this example: https://samveverka.shinyapps.io/shinyapp/)
- in my UI, when I add more selectInputs (drop downs) they do not come up on the map (it's like they're not registering as inputs -- I have no idea why?!)
- any way to add some info, like a link to my github repository, data source, etc?

Open to any other suggestions for improvement. Thanks in advance!

```
##################
GLOBAL
##################

library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(formattable)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

    ## load data ##
    murals <- read.csv("https://data.cityofchicago.org/api/views/we8h-apcf/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD",
                   stringsAsFactors = F, na = c("", "N/A", "NA"))

    ## clean data ##

      # clean Media type
      murals$Media <- str_replace(murals$Media, "spray", "Spray")
      murals$Media <- str_replace(murals$Media, "Spray + brush", "Spray and Brush")
      murals$Media <- str_replace(murals$Media, "Painting", "Paint")
      murals$Media <- str_replace(murals$Media, "LAKE VIEW", "Lake View")

      # clean Titles 
      murals$Artwork.Title <- str_replace(murals$Artwork.Title, "Where There Is Discord, Harmony:The Power of Art", "Where There Is Discord, Harmony: The Power of Art")


    ## make map easier to read with scalable circle markers ##
    circle.scaler <- function(x){((x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x)))*500}

##################
UI 
##################

# set UI
ui <- bootstrapPage(
  tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
  leafletOutput("mymap", width = "100%", height = "100%"),
  absolutePanel(top = 10, right = 10,

                theme = shinytheme("lumen"),
                shinyjs::inlineCSS(list(body = "color:White")),
                titlePanel("Chicago Neighborhood Murals"),

                selectInput("Artist.Credit", 
                            label = "Artist",
                            choices = c("All",
                                        unique(as.character(murals$Artist.Credit))))))


##################
SERVER
################## 

# set server 
server <- function(input,output, session){

    filtered <- reactive({
        murals[murals$Artist.Credit == input$Artist.Credit, ] 
    })


    # define map color markers  
    color <- colorFactor(topo.colors(3), murals$Affiliated..or.Commissioning..Organization)

    # render original leaflet map 
    output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
        leaflet(data = murals) %>%
            addTiles() %>%
            addMarkers() %>%

    # add legend     
        addLegend(
            "bottomleft", # legend position
            pal = color, # color palette
            values = ~Affiliated..or.Commissioning..Organization, # legend values
            opacity = 1,
            title = "Commissioning Organization")
         }) 



    # leaflet proxy map 
    observe(leafletProxy("mymap", data = filtered()) %>%
                addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldImagery") %>%
                clearMarkers() %>%
                addCircleMarkers(lng = ~Longitude,
                                 lat = ~Latitude,
                                 color = ~color(Affiliated..or.Commissioning..Organization),
                                 popup = paste("Artist:", murals$Artist.Credit, "<br>",
                                               "Title:", murals$Artwork.Title, "<br>",
                                               "Medium:", murals$Media, "<br>",
                                               "Location Description:", murals$Location.Description, "<br>",
                                               "Ward:", murals$Wards, "<br>",
                                               "Year:", murals$Year.Installed, "<br>",
                                               "Year Restored:", murals$Year.Restored))

                ) 
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use pickerInput and make sure that everthing is selected. Since your displayed dataset comes from filtered() and there is no artist selected in your pulldown, it will only give you a subset, which is empty.

```
##################

##################

library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(formattable)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

## load data ##
murals <- read.csv("https://data.cityofchicago.org/api/views/we8h-apcf/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD",
                   stringsAsFactors = F, na = c("", "N/A", "NA"))

## clean data ##

# clean Media type
murals$Media <- str_replace(murals$Media, "spray", "Spray")
murals$Media <- str_replace(murals$Media, "Spray + brush", "Spray and Brush")
murals$Media <- str_replace(murals$Media, "Painting", "Paint")
murals$Media <- str_replace(murals$Media, "LAKE VIEW", "Lake View")

# clean Titles 
murals$Artwork.Title <- str_replace(murals$Artwork.Title, "Where There Is Discord, Harmony:The Power of Art", "Where There Is Discord, Harmony: The Power of Art")


## make map easier to read with scalable circle markers ##
circle.scaler <- function(x){((x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x)))*500}

##################

##################

# set UI
ui <- bootstrapPage(
  tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
  leafletOutput("mymap", width = "100%", height = "100%"),
  absolutePanel(
    top = 10,
    right = 10,

    theme = shinytheme("lumen"),
    shinyjs::inlineCSS(list(body = "color:White")),
    titlePanel("Chicago Neighborhood Murals"),

    pickerInput(
      "Artist.Credit",
      label = "Artist",
      choices = c("All",
                  unique(as.character(
                    murals$Artist.Credit
                  ))),
      selected  =  murals$Artist.Credit,
      multiple = T
    )
  )
)


##################

################## 

# set server 
server <- function(input,output, session){

  filtered <- reactive({
    murals[murals$Artist.Credit == input$Artist.Credit, ] 
  })


  # define map color markers  
  color <- colorFactor(topo.colors(3), murals$Affiliated..or.Commissioning..Organization)

  # render original leaflet map 
  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(data = murals) %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addMarkers() %>%

      # add legend     
      addLegend(
        "bottomleft", # legend position
        pal = color, # color palette
        values = ~Affiliated..or.Commissioning..Organization, # legend values
        opacity = 1,
        title = "Commissioning Organization")
  }) 



  # leaflet proxy map 
  observe(leafletProxy("mymap", data = filtered()) %>%
            addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldImagery") %>%
            clearMarkers() %>%
            addCircleMarkers(lng = ~Longitude,
                             lat = ~Latitude,
                             color = ~color(Affiliated..or.Commissioning..Organization),
                             popup = paste("Artist:", murals$Artist.Credit, "<br>",
                                           "Title:", murals$Artwork.Title, "<br>",
                                           "Medium:", murals$Media, "<br>",
                                           "Location Description:", murals$Location.Description, "<br>",
                                           "Ward:", murals$Wards, "<br>",
                                           "Year:", murals$Year.Installed, "<br>",
                                           "Year Restored:", murals$Year.Restored))

  ) 
}



shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```